# Are alias and reference the same thing in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, alias

I'm not asking the difference between pointer and reference. Just a bit confused about the difference between reference and alias.

As far as I'm concerned, reference is a **data type** while **alias** is just a word describing the utility of this **data type**?

Thanks!

Comment: Alias means just another name for something existing, like a variable (reference), type (typedef), certain using clauses etc.etc

Comment: I think you mostly got it. A reference is a kind of type (specifically, a *compound* type, i.e. a type made from another type). "Alias" refers the the notion of "ways of referring to a value". Variables of reference type can be used to alias values.

Comment: You ought to explain in more detail where you saw the term "alias" and what you think is meant by it. It means several things because it's just a generic English term. These "what is the difference between" questions without any context are very poor and difficult to _properly_ answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB thank you, but i think reference is more like a syntactic sugar but not a specific data type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's what I mean, you actually answered my question that alias is just a generic English term describing the situation where a data location in memory can be accessed through different symbolic names in the program.

Comment: Okay then it would have been better if you'd straight up asked "what does 'alias' mean in C++" (and done some research on the topic), leaving all this "what is the difference" gubbins firmly out of it. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Aliasing** refers to any way to refer to the same data through different names. References and pointers are two ways of achieving this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

No, a reference is not a data-type, a reference references some other variable. Using a reference is the same as using the variable it references. It's very similar to a pointer (and it's not unlikely that the compiler treats references as pointers under the hood).

I've never heard of "alias" by itself in the context of C++, but there are *type-aliases*, created by e.g. `typedef` or `using`. There's also [*aliasing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29) which is unrelated to both references and type-aliases.

Comment: So after the source code is compiled to machine code, all the reference will be replaced by the same memory location address right? reference is more like a syntactic sugar to me.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you said you were **not** asking the difference between a pointer and a reference.

To answer what you’re asking, the word *reference* means that a variable is pointing to a location in memory.  *Alias* has a few different meanings, but the one I’ve seen most often in this context is that more than one variable are referencing the same location in memory, such as when you try to call `memcpy(p, p, n);`.  One way to make this happen is with a C++ reference, which is a term of art for a language feature similar but not identical to pointers.  Not every reference in C++ necessarily refers to something which ever has another name.  You can also do aliasing with pointers, the address operator, a call by reference, or the compiler merging constants so that "Hello" and "Hello" in two places point to the same bytes in memory, or unions.  Probably not exhaustive.

If people want to call a reference to something an “alias” even when there isn't any other variable referencing the same memory at the same time, I’m not strongly motivated to argue.

As several others have pointed out, C++14 uses the term “alias” to refer to template types declared with `using`.  (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

Comment: Failing to see the relevance here. Can you help me out?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  You said you’re **not** asking the difference between a pointer and a reference.

Comment: Completely rewrote to address the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

A type alias declaration introduces a name which can be used as a synonym for the type denoted by type-id. *It does not introduce a new type and it cannot change the meaning of an existing type name.* There is no difference between a type alias declaration and typedef declaration. This declaration may appear in block scope, class scope, or namespace scope.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias